# Java condition in while loop fails to evaluate

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

I'm having trouble with a condition inside a while loop failing to evaluate. I am trying to perform an operator once every 1/60th of a second. The following code does not print out "Done" every 1/60th of a second, it only prints every few seconds. I've checked that the delta time is fine (about 2E-6 to 5E-6 on my computer). So, I'm not sure why the code within the if statement is not occurring every 1/60th of a second.

```
    float p_dt = 1.f/60.f;

    float u_time = 0.f;

    while (true)
    {
        float t_ft = serverClock.restart().asSeconds(); //Gets the delta time

        u_time += t_ft;

        if( u_time > p_dt )
        {
            System.out.println("Done");
            u_time = 0;
        }
    }
```

Edit:
In terms of I/O speed, I don't think this is the issue. "Done" is only being printed out every 3-5 seconds, so it seems like there's a bigger issue here. Additionally, in my actual program there are some other things being evaluated in the condition. Finally, if I add print statements before the condition to keep track of `u_time`, it prints out 60 "Done"s per second. I don't think that it's an I/O issue because the function called inside the condition is only being called every 3-5 seconds, just like the print statement.

Also, serverClock is a JSFML Clock object, an OpenGL wrapper with other system tools.

Comment: Are you using a real time version of Java??

Comment: This might be related to the I/O you're performing. Do you get the overall correct number of prints or are there to few?

Comment: Not likely your problem, but the u_time=0 line should be: "u_time -= p_dt" otherwise you're losing fractional seconds every iteration which will lead to an overall loss of outputs (but not the extreme you seem to say you're seeing). Seems like the problem has to be in the serverClock line, but without any code behind that available here, not sure any more help can be provided.

Comment: System.out.println() uses a buffer and shouldn't be trusted for timings. I've seen eclipse's console even print things in the wrong order. If you really care about milliseconds, maybe you should only use on screen elements.

Comment: I'm using this technique to actually call a physics update function, and on the screen the objects only update every 3-5 seconds, so I don't think it's a problem with print speed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but it is easier to place the code here.

Would you please try this. The code should print a line with informations every 1/60s. Hope we get more information with this output.

```
    float p_dt = 1.f / 60.f;

    float u_time = 0.f;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 / 60;
    while (true) {
        float t_ft = serverClock.restart().asSeconds(); //Gets the delta time
        u_time += t_ft;
        if (timer <= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            System.out.println("t_ft: " + t_ft + " u_time: " + u_time);
            timer = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 / 60;
        }
        if (u_time > p_dt) {
            System.out.println("Done");
            u_time = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried adding a print check for `u_time` before the condition, and "Done" did print out about 60 times per second. Without this print statement, "Done" is only printed out every 3-5 seconds.

Comment: Can you post two or three line of the `System.out.println("t_ft: " + t_ft + " u_time: " + u_time);` output so we get more information, please?

Answer (score 0):

Just checked it, but couldn't find serverClock, so I hardcoded a value of your t_ft (2e-6). I also added a counter incremented inside your if condition to see the exact count. For a few tests it always appear to be incremented 60 times per second. So if you do not get "done" printet 60 times per second, it may be related to IO (note System.out.print is pretty slow on its own) or serverClock (as I did not test it).

Note: there are better ways to print something 60 times per second, for example with Timer and TimerTasks (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). Incrementing your own variable is quite risky, as you can't actually be sure your code is going to be executed constantly (the JVM and the whole system also take CPU's time, and you probably have many threads running in the background).

Note 2.: consider using Java naming convention, as well as changing names in general (t_ft, u_time and p_dt aren't most self-explaning names, are they.)